# Vertical navigation bar content gets clipped at the bottom on small screen

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm close to finishing up a vertical nav bar and it looks ok on large monitor but on small monitor (my laptop in this case) some of the content at the bottom gets covered by the taskbar. Plz see attached snapshots.

I suspect I'm missing a flexbox property. Tried setting `flex:1;` and `justify-content:space-around` without joy. I am aware setting the @ icon to `position:absolute;` will anchor it at the bottom but I think there's a more elegant solution. Thanks in advance.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital@1&display=swap');

:root {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    --text-primary: #576e75;
    --text-secondary: #35535c;
    --bg-primary: #fdf6e3;
    --bg-secondary: #f5e5b8;
    --transition-speed: 600ms;
}
.fa-primary {
    color: #df49a6;
    transition: var(--transition-speed);
}

body {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

main {
    margin-left: 5rem;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.navbar {
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: var(--bg-primary);
    transition: width 300ms ease;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.nav-item {
    height: 5rem;
}
.nav-item:last-child {
    margin-top: auto;
}

.nav-link {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 5rem;
    color: var(--text-primary);
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: var(--transition-speed);
    filter: grayscale(100%) opacity(0.7);
}
.nav-link:hover {
    filter: grayscale(0%) opacity(1);
    background: var(--bg-secondary);
    color: var(--text-secondary);
}

/* navbar on hover */
.navbar:hover {
    width: 16rem;
}
.navbar:hover .link-text {
    display: block;
}

.link-text {
    display: none;
    margin-left: 1rem;
}

.menu-button {
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: var(--text-secondary);
    background: var(--bg-secondary);
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.3ch;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

/* scrollbar */
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0.5rem;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #b6b6b6;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: rgb(233, 189, 107);
}

/* svg styles */
.nav-link svg {
    width: 2rem;
    min-width: 2rem;
    margin: 0 1.5rem;
}
.menu-button svg {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transition: var(--transition-speed);
}
.navbar:hover .menu-button svg {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
.navbar:hover .menu-button svg
{
  margin-left: 11rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="nav-item menu-button">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
          <span class="link-text logo-text">Menu</span>
          <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="angle-double-right" class="svg-inline--fa fa-angle-double-right fa-w-14" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path class="fa-primary" fill="currentColor" d="M224.3 273l-136 136c-9.4 9.4-24.6 9.4-33.9 0l-22.6-22.6c-9.4-9.4-9.4-24.6 0-33.9l96.4-96.4-96.4-96.4c-9.4-9.4-9.4-24.6 0-33.9L54.3 103c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0l136 136c9.5 9.4 9.5 24.6.1 34zm192-34l-136-136c-9.4-9.4-24.6-9.4-33.9 0l-22.6 22.6c-9.4 9.4-9.4 24.6 0 33.9l96.4 96.4-96.4 96.4c-9.4 9.4-9.4 24.6 0 33.9l22.6 22.6c9.4 9.4 24.6 9.4 33.9 0l136-136c9.4-9.2 9.4-24.4 0-33.8z"></path></svg>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
          <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="address-card" class="svg-inline--fa fa-address-card fa-w-18" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512"><path class="fa-primary" fill="currentColor" d="M528 32H48C21.5 32 0 53.5 0 80v352c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h480c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48V80c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48zm-352 96c35.3 0 64 28.7 64 64s-28.7 64-64 64-64-28.7-64-64 28.7-64 64-64zm112 236.8c0 10.6-10 19.2-22.4 19.2H86.4C74 384 64 375.4 64 364.8v-19.2c0-31.8 30.1-57.6 67.2-57.6h5c12.3 5.1 25.7 8 39.8 8s27.6-2.9 39.8-8h5c37.1 0 67.2 25.8 67.2 57.6v19.2zM512 312c0 4.4-3.6 8-8 8H360c-4.4 0-8-3.6-8-8v-16c0-4.4 3.6-8 8-8h144c4.4 0 8 3.6 8 8v16zm0-64c0 4.4-3.6 8-8 8H360c-4.4 0-8-3.6-8-8v-16c0-4.4 3.6-8 8-8h144c4.4 0 8 3.6 8 8v16zm0-64c0 4.4-3.6 8-8 8H360c-4.4 0-8-3.6-8-8v-16c0-4.4 3.6-8 8-8h144c4.4 0 8 3.6 8 8v16z"></path></svg>
            <span class="link-text">About Me</span>          
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
          <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="briefcase" class="svg-inline--fa fa-briefcase fa-w-16" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path class="fa-primary" fill="currentColor" d="M320 336c0 8.84-7.16 16-16 16h-96c-8.84 0-16-7.16-16-16v-48H0v144c0 25.6 22.4 48 48 48h416c25.6 0 48-22.4 48-48V288H320v48zm144-208h-80V80c0-25.6-22.4-48-48-48H176c-25.6 0-48 22.4-48 48v48H48c-25.6 0-48 22.4-48 48v80h512v-80c0-25.6-22.4-48-48-48zm-144 0H192V96h128v32z"></path></svg>
            <span class="link-text">Experience</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" >
          <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="tools" class="svg-inline--fa fa-tools fa-w-16" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path class="fa-primary" fill="currentColor" d="M501.1 395.7L384 278.6c-23.1-23.1-57.6-27.6-85.4-13.9L192 158.1V96L64 0 0 64l96 128h62.1l106.6 106.6c-13.6 27.8-9.2 62.3 13.9 85.4l117.1 117.1c14.6 14.6 38.2 14.6 52.7 0l52.7-52.7c14.5-14.6 14.5-38.2 0-52.7zM331.7 225c28.3 0 54.9 11 74.9 31l19.4 19.4c15.8-6.9 30.8-16.5 43.8-29.5 37.1-37.1 49.7-89.3 37.9-136.7-2.2-9-13.5-12.1-20.1-5.5l-74.4 74.4-67.9-11.3L334 98.9l74.4-74.4c6.6-6.6 3.4-17.9-5.7-20.2-47.4-11.7-99.6.9-136.6 37.9-28.5 28.5-41.9 66.1-41.2 103.6l82.1 82.1c8.1-1.9 16.5-2.9 24.7-2.9zm-103.9 82l-56.7-56.7L18.7 402.8c-25 25-25 65.5 0 90.5s65.5 25 90.5 0l123.6-123.6c-7.6-19.9-9.9-41.6-5-62.7zM64 472c-13.2 0-24-10.8-24-24 0-13.3 10.7-24 24-24s24 10.7 24 24c0 13.2-10.7 24-24 24z"></path></svg>
          <span class="link-text">Toolbox</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" >
          <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="cat" class="svg-inline--fa fa-cat fa-w-16" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path class="fa-primary" fill="currentColor" d="M290.59 192c-20.18 0-106.82 1.98-162.59 85.95V192c0-52.94-43.06-96-96-96-17.67 0-32 14.33-32 32s14.33 32 32 32c17.64 0 32 14.36 32 32v256c0 35.3 28.7 64 64 64h176c8.84 0 16-7.16 16-16v-16c0-17.67-14.33-32-32-32h-32l128-96v144c0 8.84 7.16 16 16 16h32c8.84 0 16-7.16 16-16V289.86c-10.29 2.67-20.89 4.54-32 4.54-61.81 0-113.52-44.05-125.41-102.4zM448 96h-64l-64-64v134.4c0 53.02 42.98 96 96 96s96-42.98 96-96V32l-64 64zm-72 80c-8.84 0-16-7.16-16-16s7.16-16 16-16 16 7.16 16 16-7.16 16-16 16zm80 0c-8.84 0-16-7.16-16-16s7.16-16 16-16 16 7.16 16 16-7.16 16-16 16z"></path></svg>
          <span class="link-text">Friends</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" >
          <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="camera" class="svg-inline--fa fa-camera fa-w-16" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path class="fa-primary" fill="currentColor" d="M512 144v288c0 26.5-21.5 48-48 48H48c-26.5 0-48-21.5-48-48V144c0-26.5 21.5-48 48-48h88l12.3-32.9c7-18.7 24.9-31.1 44.9-31.1h125.5c20 0 37.9 12.4 44.9 31.1L376 96h88c26.5 0 48 21.5 48 48zM376 288c0-66.2-53.8-120-120-120s-120 53.8-120 120 53.8 120 120 120 120-53.8 120-120zm-32 0c0 48.5-39.5 88-88 88s-88-39.5-88-88 39.5-88 88-88 88 39.5 88 88z"></path></svg>
          <span class="link-text">Click</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" >
          <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="guitar" class="svg-inline--fa fa-guitar fa-w-16" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path class="fa-primary" fill="currentColor" d="M502.63 39L473 9.37a32 32 0 0 0-45.26 0L381.46 55.7a35.14 35.14 0 0 0-8.53 13.79L360.77 106l-76.26 76.26c-12.16-8.76-25.5-15.74-40.1-19.14-33.45-7.78-67-.88-89.88 22a82.45 82.45 0 0 0-20.24 33.47c-6 18.56-23.21 32.69-42.15 34.46-23.7 2.27-45.73 11.45-62.61 28.44C-16.11 327-7.9 409 47.58 464.45S185 528 230.56 482.52c17-16.88 26.16-38.9 28.45-62.71 1.76-18.85 15.89-36.13 34.43-42.14a82.6 82.6 0 0 0 33.48-20.25c22.87-22.88 29.74-56.36 22-89.75-3.39-14.64-10.37-28-19.16-40.2L406 151.23l36.48-12.16a35.14 35.14 0 0 0 13.79-8.53l46.33-46.32a32 32 0 0 0 .03-45.22zM208 352a48 48 0 1 1 48-48 48 48 0 0 1-48 48z"></path></svg>
          <span class="link-text">Guitar</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" >
          <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="at" class="svg-inline--fa fa-at fa-w-16" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path class="fa-primary" fill="currentColor" d="M256 8C118.941 8 8 118.919 8 256c0 137.059 110.919 248 248 248 48.154 0 95.342-14.14 135.408-40.223 12.005-7.815 14.625-24.288 5.552-35.372l-10.177-12.433c-7.671-9.371-21.179-11.667-31.373-5.129C325.92 429.757 291.314 440 256 440c-101.458 0-184-82.542-184-184S154.542 72 256 72c100.139 0 184 57.619 184 160 0 38.786-21.093 79.742-58.17 83.693-17.349-.454-16.91-12.857-13.476-30.024l23.433-121.11C394.653 149.75 383.308 136 368.225 136h-44.981a13.518 13.518 0 0 0-13.432 11.993l-.01.092c-14.697-17.901-40.448-21.775-59.971-21.775-74.58 0-137.831 62.234-137.831 151.46 0 65.303 36.785 105.87 96 105.87 26.984 0 57.369-15.637 74.991-38.333 9.522 34.104 40.613 34.103 70.71 34.103C462.609 379.41 504 307.798 504 232 504 95.653 394.023 8 256 8zm-21.68 304.43c-22.249 0-36.07-15.623-36.07-40.771 0-44.993 30.779-72.729 58.63-72.729 22.292 0 35.601 15.241 35.601 40.77 0 45.061-33.875 72.73-58.161 72.73z"></path></svg>
          <span class="link-text">Contact</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <main class="main">
      <h1>CSS is Cool</h1>
      <p>
        I'm baby kale chips affogato ennui lumbersexual, williamsburg paleo quinoa
        iceland normcore tumeric. Kitsch coloring book retro, seitan schlitz
        tattooed biodiesel vexillologist neutra. Synth mumblecore deep v, umami
        selfies normcore gluten-free snackwave. Seitan ramps drinking vinegar
        venmo keytar, humblebrag VHS post-ironic tacos godard pour-over.
      </p>
      <p>
        Sartorial kogi taxidermy, kickstarter synth yr irony ennui everyday carry
        retro helvetica stumptown cloud bread squid echo park. Etsy cloud bread
        sartorial quinoa tacos beard mumblecore shaman tumblr pop-up. Twee retro
        fingerstache af helvetica pabst 8-bit leggings taiyaki portland ramps tbh
        tumblr vinyl. Neutra humblebrag bushwick portland subway tile plaid, offal
        scenester flexitarian cliche squid small batch palo santo. Palo santo meh
        adaptogen +1 3 wolf moon, listicle brunch ethical fanny pack everyday
        carry fam. Offal fingerstache taxidermy, man bun venmo PBR&amp;B helvetica
        thundercats everyday carry tote bag artisan cray wolf jianbing.
      </p>
      <p>
        Taxidermy thundercats whatever austin. VHS helvetica ethical, dreamcatcher
        enamel pin YOLO shabby chic locavore man bun crucifix pabst chillwave
        pop-up vegan. Air plant mlkshk ethical echo park tumeric, whatever
        crucifix godard scenester locavore pork belly yuccie vape. +1 gochujang
        put a bird on it, pork belly whatever selfies vaporware occupy banh mi
        normcore VHS. Cornhole normcore hashtag tilde. Hell of yr try-hard DIY raw
        denim banjo, enamel pin irony polaroid copper mug tofu. Dreamcatcher lomo
        literally 90's before they sold out, 3 wolf moon banh mi seitan chambray
        cliche offal tote bag occupy pug.
      </p>
      <p>
        Post-ironic hot chicken salvia yr yuccie ugh cold-pressed keffiyeh franzen
        viral taxidermy mustache slow-carb crucifix vape. Taiyaki yuccie hell of
        tacos PBR&amp;B, kitsch meggings tbh truffaut kickstarter mixtape af kogi.
        Fingerstache vegan tofu waistcoat gentrify cray. Drinking vinegar 3 wolf
        moon health goth craft beer master cleanse. Letterpress health goth 8-bit
        chillwave craft beer brooklyn. Chicharrones master cleanse 8-bit,
        mumblecore copper mug messenger bag poutine lomo kale chips flannel. Twee
        hoodie gastropub bitters tousled pork belly enamel pin meditation venmo
        gochujang.
      </p>
      <p>
        Next level selfies cronut ethical. Tofu tumblr you probably haven't heard
        of them, man braid literally forage swag chillwave. Pug yr flannel
        tumeric. Coloring book yr chillwave snackwave, shoreditch shaman gentrify
        typewriter tumeric DIY copper mug small batch. Scenester waistcoat YOLO
        hexagon kombucha poke 8-bit meditation. Selvage scenester forage
        williamsburg. Hoodie fingerstache tacos mustache, hashtag quinoa next
        level sartorial craft beer retro disrupt lo-fi.
      </p>
      <p>
        YOLO twee keytar farm-to-table flexitarian cardigan polaroid lumbersexual
        adaptogen drinking vinegar echo park dreamcatcher. Brunch shoreditch
        dreamcatcher iPhone knausgaard plaid edison bulb letterpress ethical yr
        fanny pack. Typewriter portland woke glossier cronut, post-ironic migas
        gentrify letterpress cray brunch lyft 8-bit master cleanse. Pitchfork
        thundercats organic pour-over unicorn lomo.
      </p>
      <p>
        Ugh yr tacos aesthetic everyday carry, tumeric selvage cliche skateboard.
        Wolf truffaut enamel pin vexillologist poutine. Hoodie roof party pabst,
        cardigan letterpress af disrupt +1 subway tile chillwave live-edge
        meggings next level readymade. Master cleanse gentrify hashtag, stumptown
        fam single-origin coffee occupy dreamcatcher air plant viral vexillologist
        enamel pin meggings. Tumblr chambray pickled microdosing austin scenester
        green juice.
      </p>
      <p>
        Austin four dollar toast church-key, vaporware hoodie edison bulb jean
        shorts sustainable williamsburg plaid helvetica scenester lomo humblebrag.
        Meditation tumblr kickstarter ennui williamsburg taiyaki pabst pour-over.
        8-bit godard cred, chillwave enamel pin skateboard you probably haven't
        heard of them. Meditation before they sold out single-origin coffee swag
        try-hard jianbing slow-carb shaman leggings. Palo santo shabby chic
        whatever man bun. Master cleanse wayfarers single-origin coffee pork belly
        cronut, normcore cliche jianbing before they sold out tousled shabby chic
        af pop-up gentrify. Direct trade la croix vexillologist jianbing,
        flexitarian selvage try-hard stumptown polaroid shaman wayfarers poke
        ramps food truck swag.
      </p>
      <p>
        Pok pok lumbersexual wayfarers, direct trade leggings poutine truffaut
        kitsch. Seitan aesthetic master cleanse squid coloring book banh mi YOLO
        vegan locavore vexillologist readymade next level pop-up edison bulb.
        Selvage knausgaard literally, quinoa photo booth 3 wolf moon microdosing
        freegan yuccie. Truffaut gentrify lomo put a bird on it waistcoat. Ugh
        austin distillery, tbh actually pork belly snackwave artisan mixtape
        quinoa vexillologist pok pok polaroid listicle readymade.
      </p>
      <p>
        Hammock letterpress prism dreamcatcher truffaut shabby chic vice
        cold-pressed. Franzen pug fashion axe before they sold out, tumblr irony
        kogi actually af bushwick banh mi. Snackwave bicycle rights tofu
        dreamcatcher tote bag pour-over meditation raw denim fanny pack. Pop-up
        retro taiyaki meditation twee gastropub VHS etsy. Semiotics gochujang
        street art normcore, edison bulb farm-to-table pour-over taxidermy
        brooklyn.
      </p>
      <p>
        I'm baby kale chips affogato ennui lumbersexual, williamsburg paleo quinoa
        iceland normcore tumeric. Kitsch coloring book retro, seitan schlitz
        tattooed biodiesel vexillologist neutra. Synth mumblecore deep v, umami
        selfies normcore gluten-free snackwave. Seitan ramps drinking vinegar
        venmo keytar, humblebrag VHS post-ironic tacos godard pour-over.
      </p>
      <p>
        Sartorial kogi taxidermy, kickstarter synth yr irony ennui everyday carry
        retro helvetica stumptown cloud bread squid echo park. Etsy cloud bread
        sartorial quinoa tacos beard mumblecore shaman tumblr pop-up. Twee retro
        fingerstache af helvetica pabst 8-bit leggings taiyaki portland ramps tbh
        tumblr vinyl. Neutra humblebrag bushwick portland subway tile plaid, offal
        scenester flexitarian cliche squid small batch palo santo. Palo santo meh
        adaptogen +1 3 wolf moon, listicle brunch ethical fanny pack everyday
        carry fam. Offal fingerstache taxidermy, man bun venmo PBR&amp;B helvetica
        thundercats everyday carry tote bag artisan cray wolf jianbing.
      </p>
      <p>
        Taxidermy thundercats whatever austin. VHS helvetica ethical, dreamcatcher
        enamel pin YOLO shabby chic locavore man bun crucifix pabst chillwave
        pop-up vegan. Air plant mlkshk ethical echo park tumeric, whatever
        crucifix godard scenester locavore pork belly yuccie vape. +1 gochujang
        put a bird on it, pork belly whatever selfies vaporware occupy banh mi
        normcore VHS. Cornhole normcore hashtag tilde. Hell of yr try-hard DIY raw
        denim banjo, enamel pin irony polaroid copper mug tofu. Dreamcatcher lomo
        literally 90's before they sold out, 3 wolf moon banh mi seitan chambray
        cliche offal tote bag occupy pug.
      </p>
      <p>
        Post-ironic hot chicken salvia yr yuccie ugh cold-pressed keffiyeh franzen
        viral taxidermy mustache slow-carb crucifix vape. Taiyaki yuccie hell of
        tacos PBR&amp;B, kitsch meggings tbh truffaut kickstarter mixtape af kogi.
        Fingerstache vegan tofu waistcoat gentrify cray. Drinking vinegar 3 wolf
        moon health goth craft beer master cleanse. Letterpress health goth 8-bit
        chillwave craft beer brooklyn. Chicharrones master cleanse 8-bit,
        mumblecore copper mug messenger bag poutine lomo kale chips flannel. Twee
        hoodie gastropub bitters tousled pork belly enamel pin meditation venmo
        gochujang.
      </p>
      <p>
        Next level selfies cronut ethical. Tofu tumblr you probably haven't heard
        of them, man braid literally forage swag chillwave. Pug yr flannel
        tumeric. Coloring book yr chillwave snackwave, shoreditch shaman gentrify
        typewriter tumeric DIY copper mug small batch. Scenester waistcoat YOLO
        hexagon kombucha poke 8-bit meditation. Selvage scenester forage
        williamsburg. Hoodie fingerstache tacos mustache, hashtag quinoa next
        level sartorial craft beer retro disrupt lo-fi.
      </p>
      <p>
        YOLO twee keytar farm-to-table flexitarian cardigan polaroid lumbersexual
        adaptogen drinking vinegar echo park dreamcatcher. Brunch shoreditch
        dreamcatcher iPhone knausgaard plaid edison bulb letterpress ethical yr
        fanny pack. Typewriter portland woke glossier cronut, post-ironic migas
        gentrify letterpress cray brunch lyft 8-bit master cleanse. Pitchfork
        thundercats organic pour-over unicorn lomo.
      </p>
      <p>
        Ugh yr tacos aesthetic everyday carry, tumeric selvage cliche skateboard.
        Wolf truffaut enamel pin vexillologist poutine. Hoodie roof party pabst,
        cardigan letterpress af disrupt +1 subway tile chillwave live-edge
        meggings next level readymade. Master cleanse gentrify hashtag, stumptown
        fam single-origin coffee occupy dreamcatcher air plant viral vexillologist
        enamel pin meggings. Tumblr chambray pickled microdosing austin scenester
        green juice.
      </p>
      <p>
        Austin four dollar toast church-key, vaporware hoodie edison bulb jean
        shorts sustainable williamsburg plaid helvetica scenester lomo humblebrag.
        Meditation tumblr kickstarter ennui williamsburg taiyaki pabst pour-over.
        8-bit godard cred, chillwave enamel pin skateboard you probably haven't
        heard of them. Meditation before they sold out single-origin coffee swag
        try-hard jianbing slow-carb shaman leggings. Palo santo shabby chic
        whatever man bun. Master cleanse wayfarers single-origin coffee pork belly
        cronut, normcore cliche jianbing before they sold out tousled shabby chic
        af pop-up gentrify. Direct trade la croix vexillologist jianbing,
        flexhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#itarian selvage try-hard stumptown polaroid shaman wayfarers poke
        ramps food truck swag.
      </p>
      <p>
        Pok pok lumbersexual wayfarers, direct trade leggings poutine truffaut
        kitsch. Seitan aesthetic master cleanse squid coloring book banh mi YOLO
        vegan locavore vexillologist readymade next level pop-up edison bulb.
        Selvage knausgaard literally, quinoa photo booth 3 wolf moon microdosing
        freegan yuccie. Truffaut gentrify lomo put a bird on it waistcoat. Ugh
        austin distillery, tbh actually pork belly snackwave artisan mixtape
        quinoa vexillologist pok pok polaroid listicle readymade.
      </p>
      <p>
        Hammock letterpress prism dreamcatcher truffaut shabby chic vice
        cold-pressed. Franzen pug fashion axe before they sold out, tumblr irony
        kogi actually af bushwick banh mi. Snackwave bicycle rights tofu
        dreamcatcher tote bag pour-over meditation raw denim fanny pack. Pop-up
        retro taiyaki meditation twee gastropub VHS etsy. Semiotics gochujang
        street art normcore, edison bulb farm-to-table pour-over taxidermy
        brooklyn.
      </p>
    </main>
</body>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you inspect your app on different devices, in developer window. You will find different heights of your sidebar.

Comment: Try removing these two properties from your CSS. .nav-item {
  height: 5rem;
}
.nav-item:last-child {
  margin-top: auto;
}

Comment: I would suggest you look into [@media rules](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)